# Print an InputStream on System.out without changing the stream using apache commons

Tags: java, stream, inputstream, apache-commons

What I am trying to achieve here is have more debug output by printing out the contents of an InputStream using apache-commons. It seems like I am changing the stream itself in the process.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
IOUtils.copy(is, System.out); //Happily Prints out contents of file.txt
IOUtils.copy(is, System.out); //Doesn't print anything
```

Why does copying a stream using IOUtils change the stream? I tried cloning the stream, and then printing it out but still no luck. I tried CloseShieldInputStream from apache commons to clone.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
CloseShieldInputStream csis = new CloseShieldInputStream(is);
IOUtils.copy(csis, System.out);//Happily Prints out contents of file.txt
IOUtils.copy(is, System.out);//Still Doesn't print anything
```

Can someone explain why they call these methods 'copy' even though the source stream loses its contents? How can I print out a stream without worrying about losing its contents?

**EDIT:**

This code (except where the stream gets initialized) is pretty deep inside a 3rd-Party library and the stream is passed after going through several methods. It's hard to figure out where the stream got initialized, and display it there and then reinitialize. I am desperately trying to display this stream and still keep it unaltered.

Comment: You can't.  Generally speaking, an `InputStream` can be read from only once.  You'll need to reopen the stream if you want to use its contents again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.out` stream is not being changed. What is happening is that once the contents of `is` are read, they have been consumed and you can't read them again. What you have to do to fix this is re-initialize `is` before the second call.

Comment: So you're saying I can't print out the stream and still retain the contents of the stream and there's possibly no other way but do an IO operation to read in the stream again.

Comment: Yes, unless you read the stream into a byte array and create a new `ByteArrayInputStream` when needed.